# Simplify: 0.3cos(4t) + 0.2cos(6t) in terms of cos( ) function.

Tags: trigonometry

Please help me with this,

> I need to compare the equation $$s(t)= 50[1+ 0.3\cos(4t) +
>  0.2\cos(6t)]\cos10t$$ with the  given general equation $$s(t)=A[1+ u \cos(bt)]\cos(ct)$$ .

I don't know but it might be something like simplifying the form ***xcos(a)+ycos(b)*** into ***zcos⁡(c)*** form .
So, if only i knew how to simplify the equation to its general form, it would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that there are two harmonic waves in the equation, and thus it cannot be simplified with a *single* wave.

Note that

$$ 0.3 \cos(4 t) + 0.2 \cos(6 t) = 0.5 \cos(t)\cos(5 t) + 0.1 \sin(t)\sin(5 t) $$ since

$$ \begin{align} \frac{6t+4t}{2} &= 5t \\ \frac{6t-4t}{2} & = t \\ 0.3+0.2 &= 0.5 \\ 0.3-0.2 &= 0.1 \end{align} $$

I am using the trigonometric identity:

$$ u_1 \cos(a_1 t) + u_2 \cos(a_2 t) = v_1 \cos(b_1 t)\cos(b_2 t) + v_2 \sin(b_1 t)\sin(b_2 t) $$

where

$$\begin{align}
  b_1 & = \frac{a_2+a_1}{2} \\
  b_2 & = \frac{a_2-a_1}{2} \\
  v_1 & = u_1+u_2 \\
  v_2 & = u_1-u_2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $a, b, c$ are distinct non negative real numbers then
the functions $\cos(at)$, $\cos(bt)$ and $\cos(ct)$ are [linearly independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence). See [Show linear independence of cosines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494623/show-linear-independence-of-cosines).

This means, for example that you can't find $u$ and $b$ such that $0.3\cos(4t) +0.2\cos(6t)=u \cos(bt)$ for ALL $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: so, does it mean i can't compare the two equations ? @RobertZ

Comment: @BishnuSubedi Yes, you can't find $u$ and $b$ such that $0.3\cos(4t) +0.2\cos(6t)=u \cos(bt)$ for ALL $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: thank you for your help. appreciate it .